# SimpleDateFormat does not process DD properly

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to get a format like this:

```
2013-06-15-17-45
```

I do the following in my code:

```
  Date d = new Date();
  SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("YYYY_MM_DD_HH_mm");          

  String fileName = "D:\\"+ft.format(d)+".csv";
```

But I don't get the DD right. It creates a file with a name like this:

```
D:\\2013_12_340_13_53.csv
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capital "D" is day of year; lowercase "d" is day of month ([`SimpleDateFormat` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)).  Try:

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm");
```

Also, capital "Y" is "week year"; usually lowercase "y" ("year") is used.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by rgettman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20435661/642706) is correct.

### Joda-Time

Here's the same kind of code, but using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 with Java 7.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTime now = new DateTime();

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm" );

System.out.println( "now ISO 8601 format: " + now.toString() );
System.out.println( "now in special format: " + formatter.print( now ) );
```

When run…

```
now ISO 8601 format: 2013-12-06T20:02:52.070-08:00
now in special format: 2013_12_06_20_02
```

### Suggestion: ISO 8601 Style

I do the same kind of date-time in labeling files and folders. I suggest using a format closer to the standard ISO 8601 format.

Joda-Time has a built-in format close to what we need, [`dateHourMinute()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateHourMinute()) on [`ISODateTimeFormat`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html) class.

For use with file systems, we should avoid using slash (Unix), backslash (MS Windows), and colon (Mac) characters. By starting with ISO format, we have no slash or backslash characters. That leaves only the colons from the time portion, to be removed with a call to `replaceAll` method of `String` class in Java.

You may wish to replace the `T` as well.

```java
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTime now = new DateTime();
System.out.println( "now: " + now );

DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinute();
String formatted = formatter.print( now ).replaceAll( ":", "." ).replaceAll( "T", "_" );
System.out.println( "formatted: " + formatted );
```

When run…

```
now: 2013-12-06T21:10:07.382-08:00
formatted: 2013-12-06_21.10
```

### UTC

Furthermore, for server-side or other serious work consider converting to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) rather than your local time to avoid ambiguity.

```java
    DateTime now = new DateTime();
    System.out.println( "now: " + now );

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinute();
    String formatted = formatter.print( now.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC ) ).replaceAll( ":", "." ).replaceAll( "T", "_" ) + "Z";
    System.out.println( "formatted: " + formatted );
```

When run…

```
now: 2013-12-06T21:21:00.128-08:00
formatted: 2013-12-07_05.21Z
```