# java jodatime cannot get back to 1st after the end of month

Tags: java, jodatime

I am writing a program which is supposed to return the date day by day. I am using *DateTime.plusDays(1)* but it return 32 of Feb after 31 of Jan. I have simplified my code as below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        DateTime datetime = new DateTime(1900, 1, 31, 0, 0, 0);
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYYMMDD");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(datetime.toString(fmt));
            datetime = datetime.plusDays(1);
        }
    }
```

The result I got is

> ```
> 19000131
> 19000232
> 19000233......
> ```

Could anyone please advise? Thanks in advance.

Comment: problem is in the DateTimeFormatter, try Printing it as a java.util.Date to see the result!!

Comment: Try yyyyMMdd as date format. Letter case matters here. DD is day of year.

Comment: Besides, `YYYY` is almost certainly not what you want. Use the lower-case version `yyyy`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleDateFormat does not process DD properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435638/simpledateformat-does-not-process-dd-properly)

Comment: @iantang Please search StackOverflow before posting. You would have hundreds of examples of working code to compare to your troubled code.

Answer (score 0):

try using this with out joda time to get the same result ( with java standard calendar )

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(1900, 0, 31); // month is 0 based
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%4d%02d%02d", calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }
}
```

**--UPDATE--**

if u insisist on using joda, u can use this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTime datetime = new DateTime(1900, 1, 31, 0, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%4d%02d%02d\n", datetime.getYear(), datetime.getMonthOfYear(), datetime.getDayOfMonth());
        datetime = datetime.plusDays(1);
    }
}
```